# SWI prolog, char_type, ascii / alnum, why so many chars? how to fix it?

Tags: character-encoding, prolog, swi-prolog

I've just wanted to check, what chars SWI-prolog treats as 'alnum'. 
My question clause was:

```
    findall(X,char_type(X,alnum),Lalnum),length(Lalnum,N).
```

and the SWI's answer:

```
    Lalnum = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'|...],
    N = 816459.
```

I was very surprised - why so many?
Then I've decided to check pure 'ascii' set - after all, according to the doc page:

```
    http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=char_type/2
```

there are only 128 of them (7 bit char set).
My obvious question was:

```
     findall(X,char_type(X,ascii),Lascii),length(Lascii,N).
```

and the SWI's answer:

```
    Lascii = ['\000\', '\001\', '\002\', '\003\', '\004\', 
    '\005\', '\006\', '\a', '\b'|...], 
    N = 2176.
```

I was surprised even more than before...
What is wrong? Where is the problem? 
With my question? With my SWI-prolog installation? With my system?
It is:

```
SWI Prolog 7.7.13, with ascii encoding:

    current_prolog_flag(encoding,X).
    X = ascii.

Win 8.1 64bit, with code page 852.
```

And how to fix it?

Thank you in advance

EDIT:
probably I've found the answer to my second question: 'how to fix it'.
It seems, that additional clause:

```
    sort(Lascii,SortedLascii)
```

removes repetitions and leaves the basic set of 128 chars alone.

but I still do not understand why the first clause generates so many results...???

Comment: Could you add `writeln(Lascii)` at the end of your ASCII findall query and add (part of) the output to the question? It might show you what characters are considered ASCII characters. The sorting stuff suggests that SWI might enumerate the same characters several times, which would be weird. As for the `alnum` part, that may be related. But also, there are a *lot* of `alnum` characters: `?- char_type('民', alnum).
true.`

Comment: Hello @IsabelleNewbie - thank you for your answer. 
I've tried to save results of my query to file - with:
tell('d:/results.txt'),<my query>, told, flush.
After examining that file I see that the ascii set (char(\000)..char(\1ff) was just repeated 17 times - thus I've received 2176 chars (bytes) instead of just 128.
The same was, when I've saved results of query about all other char types (alnum, alpha, csym,... and so on) - eg for 'alnum' I have got 816459 chars instead of 48027 in the set.

And I do not know where this repetition comes from...

Answer (score 1):

The reason for so many characters is Unicode. It'll return all relevant characters depending on your current locale.

### Including Unicode:

Letters only:

```
?- :(C, char_type(C, alpha), L), length(L, Len).                     
L = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'|...],
Len = 2568.
```

Alphanumeric characters:

```
?- findall(C, char_type(C, alnum), L), length(L, Len).
L = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'|...],
Len = 2578.
```

### Now ASCII only:

Letters only:

```
?- findall(C, (char_type(C, alpha), char_type(C, ascii)), L), length(L, Len).
L = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'|...],
Len = 52.
```

Alphanumerics:

```
?- findall(C, (char_type(C, alnum), char_type(C, ascii)), L), length(L, Len).
L = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'|...],
Len = 62.
```

### What's causing the confusion?

Because number of returned items is too high, the output is cut and omitted items are replaced with ellipsis. More details here: 
https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html

To change this behavior and see a complete output use the following config option:

```
set_prolog_flag(
    answer_write_options,
    [
        quoted(true),
        portray(true),
        spacing(next_argument)
    ]
),
```

This way you'll see all Unicode characters and won't be confused any more.
Note that the only difference from default is absence of `max_depth(10)`.